# Using SMS Retriever API with Instant Apps

Tags: android, sms, android-instant-apps

I have a functioning instant app and I've successfully incorporated the SMS Retriever API in several apps, but the two don't seem to function together.  Is there a way to make them function together, or does there exist documentation about this not being supported?

```
public class SmsClient {

    private SmsReceiver smsReceiver;

    public interface GoogleTaskListener extends OnSuccessListener<Void>, OnFailureListener {
    }

    public SmsClient(@NonNull VerificationCodeListener verificationCodeListener,
                     int codeLength) {
        this.smsReceiver = new SmsReceiver(verificationCodeListener, codeLength);
    }

    public void attach(Context context) {
        SmsRetrieverClient client = SmsRetriever.getClient(context);
        Task<Void> startSmsReceiverTask = client.startSmsRetriever();

        GoogleTaskListener googleTaskListener = new GoogleTaskListener() {
            @Override
            public void onSuccess(Void v) {
                Timber.i("Sms task succeeded!");
            }

            @Override
            public void onFailure(@NonNull Exception e) {
                Timber.e("Sms task failed."); //Message "17: API: SmsRetriever.API is not available on this device."
            }
        };

        startSmsReceiverTask.addOnSuccessListener(googleTaskListener);
        startSmsReceiverTask.addOnFailureListener(googleTaskListener);

        IntentFilter intentFilter = new IntentFilter();
        intentFilter.addAction(SmsRetriever.SMS_RETRIEVED_ACTION);
        context.registerReceiver(smsReceiver, intentFilter);
    }

    public void detach(Context context) {
        context.unregisterReceiver(smsReceiver);
    }
}
```

When starting the SMS Retriever with startSmsRetriever() in a regular app, onSuccess is called.

When attempting to start the SMS Retriever in the same application run as an Instant App, onFailure is called with the error message *17: API: SmsRetriever.API is not available on this device.*

Ultimately, we're hoping to have a one-time-password delivered by SMS automatically processed by a running instant app to verify a session.  Any information on the subject would be helpful.

I'm currently running this in the Pixel 3 (API 28) emulator.

Comment: No issues here, I copied the sample from https://developers.google.com/identity/sms-retriever/request#2_start_the_sms_retriever and ran on a Pixel 3 API 28 emulator (ok too for a real device, Pixel 2 API 29). Try re-creating your emulator.

Comment: @TWL Please verify that you ran the SMS retriever as an **Instant App** in the emulator; that the app was not actually installed.

I have tried this in a newly created emulator, and there is no change.

Comment: yep, I have checked `Deploy as instant app` and the app settings confirms it too `instant app`. Have you tried on a real device?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As TWL commented, it does work.  It just doesn't work in the emulator.